# Rails automatically send tweet after twitter authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, devise

I have an ruby on rails application that uses devise and omniauth-twitter gem to handle user management and authenication.  Users can only login through twitter.  I already have the application authenticating, however I would like to allow users to write a tweet; and if they are not logged in, authenticate through twitter then have the tweet they wrote before the authentication post to twitter.

I was wondering what is the best way to go about doing that?

Can I capture a request if a user is not logged in, log them in, then preform the captured request?

Just not sure how to go about doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you request an URL when logged out, devise asks for authentication and then redirects to the requested URL after you log in the application. Did you already tried to send the tweet when logged out? Maybe it's already doing what you want...

Comment: Worst case scenario you can still cache your request somewhere and fetch it back once you get the callback of successful authentication.

Comment: @thaleshcv the original request is done using ajax.  I made it a 'regular request' and tested it but I am getting redirect to my homepage. (That may be something I put in, I have to check my code again.)

Comment: @LukeS This is what I figured I had to do, but was looking to see if there was some other ‘easier’ way to do it.

Comment: Maybe you could open the authentication page in an iframe or something and close it once the process is done, that way you never leave your form page, you resubmit and it will find the cookies of your auth session and post it?

Comment: @LukeS Thanks.  I decided for now, if the user is not logged in, to active a lightbox when a user tries to tweet in my app that just force the user to login and then redirects back to the page they where on.

It is not the user experience I want to offer but it will have to do for now until i can get back to this part of the project.  Thanks again!